Power Blow -- long concentration for a single attack?
I'm playing a martial artist in an ongoing play-by-post (nine years and counting, or about five weeks for the characters).
One of the template skills I took at character creation is Power Blow; this allows temporarily doubling ST for a single attack, making fists and feet much more effective against opponents with significant DR (above 2 or so) or high HP.
Power Blow requires prolonged concentration to be effective unless taken at very high (20+, preferably higher than that) skill; as long as 32 combat rounds to use the skill without a skill penalty.  The description of the skill (B215) is unclear on whether one needs to restart the concentration period at the "instant" level of -10 to skill after making a Power Blow attempt, or whether, once activated, one can continue to roll the Power Blow skill and spend 1 FP per additional attack.
Is there official clarification on this?  Can I concentrate long enough to get to, say, -2 skill (that's only 8 seconds) and then roll for each attack in the ensuing battle, or do I simply need to spend the points to ramp the skill up to 20 or higher to be able to use Power Blow effectively with a minimum of delay?

TL;DR: It appears to be the community consensus that you do need to concentrate for each use, but I couldn't find any sort of proof.
This is an interesting question because I'd never considered it before. I can't find any official examples clearly showing that you need to concentrate before each use of Power Blow (or the family of similar cinematic martial arts skills). I did find this Pyramid Q&A which says you can't concentrate on two skills at once, but that's (a) from the previous edition and (b) answering a different question.
There are also forum threads which seem to me to assume that Power Blow etc require the concentration for each attack, and which published GURPS authors often participate in, e.g. this one.
I found a thread here where it is stated that the use of the manoeuvre must be immediately after the concentration is completed.
All of this is just to show my working when I say that I couldn't find any official clarification on this, and don't think it exists.
My personal opinion is being able to 're-use' the concentration would require specific rules explaining how long it lasts for (one fight? an hour? a day?). As this is lacking, I don't think that's the intention of the rules.

I think you're right. I've always read it that way, and in GMing a character who had Power Blow, it was always treated that way without the player feeling let down. He tended to use it for jumping, rather than attacks, until he got it high enough to use instantly.

If I'd read the skill description more thoroughly during my character build (May 2015!) I'm sure I'd have found a way to stuff more points into it myself.  As it is, I've been working it up for a while (though on PbP with one or two posts per character per day, that takes a long time).  FWIW, it's somewhat useful at SL15, in that I can reuse it around the same frequency as cocking, loading, and aiming a crossbow, as long as I can roll at least average.
